# Referencing the bytes malloc'd beyond the size of a struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the memory allocated beyond the size of a struct to mimic a 'payload'
and to allow that payload contain a pointer to another struct. Can someone tell me if this is possible or if what i'm trying to do is not feasible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define ptrsize sizeof(char*)

typedef struct s{
  int i;
  short j;
  long k;
}S;

S *salloc(int sz,int i,short j,long k){
  S *m=malloc(sizeof(S)+sz);
  m->i=i;m->j=j;m->k=k;
  return m;
}

char *goToData(S *m){
  char* dataloc=(char*)m+sizeof(S);
  return dataloc;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){

  char a[]={"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
  S *mys=salloc(26,2,3,100);              // struct * to size 26+sizeof(S) & set struct vars
  char *mydp=goToData(mys);               // get the address of the payload 
  memcpy(mydp,a,sizeof(a));               // copy a into the payload

  S *mysc=salloc(ptrsize,1,2,3);          // allocate a container struct

  char *datapw=goToData(mysc);            // go to the first byte of the payload of mysc
  (*(S**)datapw)=mys;                     // want to point at mys -- is this possible?

  printf("%d\n",ptrsize);
  printf("addr mys              %x\n",(unsigned int)mys);
  printf("addr mysc             %x\n",(unsigned int)mysc);
  printf("addr mysc | *datapw   %x\n",(unsigned int)*datapw);  // from here would like to be indirectly reference mys

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `goToData()` function seems to be sound.  The memory allocation is sound, though you don't record how big the space is that was allocated after the structure.

There's a buffer overflow here:

```
char a[] = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
S *mys = salloc(26,2,3,100);              // struct * to size 26+sizeof(S) & set struct vars
char *mydp = goToData(mys);               // get the address of the payload 
memcpy(mydp, a, sizeof(a));               // copy a into the payload
```

You allocated 26 bytes but you're copying 27 (`sizeof(a) == 27` because `sizeof()` counts the NUL `'\0'` at the end).  That is a recipe for disaster.  Don't use elegant variation in C; use consistency.  Either use 26 in both places or `sizeof(a)`, but not a mixture.

<s>If there's a problem, it is with the line:</s>

```
(*(S**)datapw)=mys;                     // want to point at mys -- is this possible?
```

<s>I'm not even sure I understand what you're trying to do here, but it doesn't look good at all.</s>

Although `datapw` is aligned for use as an `S *`, you haven't allocated enough space for that to be used.  I'm not clear that you should be converting it to a `S**` before dereferencing.

If you are trying to make the space after the structure pointed at by `mysc` contain a pointer to the structure pointed at by `mys`, then you had better have a really good reason for not including the pointer in the structure.  A *really, really* good reason.

However, that code is accurate, despite my strong misgivings.  But it is extremely opaque.

I think you should get the result you want with:

```
*((S **)datapw) = mys;
```

I hate to think what the strict-aliasing implications are, though you might be OK since there is an exemption of some sort for `char *`.

<s>So, revisit that statement and work out what you are trying to do - because what you've written doesn't do it, whatever it was.</s>

```
printf("addr mysc | *datapw   %x\n",(unsigned int)*datapw);
```

This has some issues.  Since `datapw` is a `char *`, `*datapw` is going to be a character.  Probably not what you had in mind.  `(unsigned int)*(S **)` is what you need, I think.

The rest is OK-ish, though on a 64-bit system, addresses are too big for `%x`.  You'll get away with on a 32-bit system, but you should use either `%p` with `(void *)` casts, or `"%" PRIXPTR` from `<inttypes.h>` with a `(uintptr_t)` cast.

I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define ptrsize sizeof(char*)

typedef struct s
{
    int   i;
    short j;
    long  k;
} S;

static S *salloc(int sz, int i, short j, long k)
{
    S *m = malloc(sizeof(S) + sz);
    m->i = i;
    m->j = j;
    m->k = k;
    return m;
}

static char *goToData(S *m)
{
    char *dataloc = (char*)m + sizeof(S);
    return dataloc;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    S *mys = salloc(sizeof(a), 2, 3, 100);     // struct * to size 26+sizeof(S) & set struct vars
    char *mydp = goToData(mys);                // get the address of the payload 
    memcpy(mydp, a, sizeof(a));                // copy a into the payload
    S *mysc = salloc(ptrsize, 1, 2, 3);        // allocate a container struct
    char *datapw  = goToData(mysc);            // go to the first byte of the payload of mysc
    *((S **)datapw) = mys;                     // want to point at mys -- is this possible?

    printf("%zu\n", ptrsize);
    printf("addr mys              %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)mys);
    printf("addr mysc             %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)mysc);
    printf("addr mysc | *datapw   %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)*(S **)datapw);

    return 0;
}
```

(I compile with `-Wmissing-prototypes`; the `static` in front of the functions prevents the compiler warning me about these functions.  Since you aren't using the arguments to `main()`, I replaced `argc` and `argv` with `void` for the same reason - to avoid compiler warnings.)

When I ran it under `valgrind` on a Mac (MacOS X 10.7.2, GCC 4.2.1, Valgrind 3.7.0), I got a clean run with the data output:

```
8
addr mys              100005120
addr mysc             100005190
addr mysc | *datapw   100005120
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the accepted answer, I would change the struct to:

```
typedef struct s{
  int i;
  short j;
  long k;
   char data[1]; //<- start of optional data
}S;

static S *salloc(int sz, int i, short j, long k)
{
    S *m = malloc((sizeof(S)-1) + sz );
    m->i = i;
    m->j = j;
    m->k = k;
    return m;
}
```

Then you don't need the goToData function as S already has a pointer to it.

```
int main(void)
{
  char a[] = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
  S *mys = salloc(sizeof(a), 2, 3, 100);     // struct * to size 26+sizeof(S) & set struct vars
   memcpy(&mys->data, a, sizeof(a));                // copy a into the payload
  S *mysc = salloc(ptrsize, 1, 2, 3);        // allocate a container struct
  char *datapw  = &mysc->data;            // go to the first byte of the payload of mysc
  *((S **)datapw) = mys;                     // want to point at mys -- is this possible?

  printf("%zu\n", ptrsize);
  printf("addr mys              %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)mys);
  printf("addr mysc             %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)mysc);
  printf("addr mysc | *datapw   %" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)*(S **)datapw);

  return 0;
}
```

I remember a really old Microsoft DOS compiler supporting:

```
typedef struct s{
  int i;
  short j;
  long k;
   char data[0]; //<- start of optional data
}S;
```

which meant that sizeof(S) didn't include the optional data, but gave you a pointer to the start of the data for you to use it.

Comment: Apparently, current gcc does support `char data[0]` declaration too.